# How to structure .net projects while working with docker

Tags: .net, docker

Im bulding system that is based on so called events, basicly just a c# records that are send to the queue and then processed by consumer. I have a "Shared" class library that has all the events to keep it simple and easy to mange, however my Dockerfile can't see that shared library because it lives in another folder, here is the tree:

```
my-system:
|-service1
|--Dockerfile
|--service1.API
|---service1.API.csproj
|-service2
|--Dockerfile
|--service2.API
|---service2.API.csproj
|-Shared
|--Shared.csproj
```

[image: folder strucutre]

How do I manage that?

Answer (score 0):

It's all about the build context. The build context is the directory location whose contents can be made available during the Docker build via `COPY` instructions in the Dockerfile. If you want to have access to service1 and shared directories from your Dockerfile, you need to set the build context to the common root directory of those two directories: `my-system`.

As for the location of the Dockerfiles, they can be placed anywhere and have any name you want. The `docker build` command lets you specify the explicit Dockerfile name, with the `-f` option and the build context directory (the required argument).

But it may be more understandable to place the Dockerfiles in the location where you would set the build context. So you could place the two Dockerfiles in the `my-system` directory with names like: `Dockerfile.service1` and `Dockerfile.service2`. It's up to you where they're located though.

But the content of those Dockerfiles would need to be adjusted to be in relation to the build context directory, not the location of the Dockerfile. So  if the build context is `my-system` then the `COPY` instructions in the Dockerfiles need to be relative to that location.